# Is indirect recursion possible in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I tried searching online but did not find any answer to this particular question. In python there are no function declarations and a function can't be used until it has been defined.

Does this mean that indirect recursion is impossible in python?

And is there a way around this by using some modules?

Comment: Have you given it a try?

Comment: Indirect recursion __is__ possible. The body of a function is not validated (apart from syntax), it can be created with a call to a function that does not exist or access a variable that does not exist. So long as both functions have been created before the first is called there should be no issue

Comment: @Iain Shelvington.. ohh ok.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

No, it is possible

```
def f():
    print('from f')
    g()


def g():
    print('from g')
    f()
```

"a function can't be used until it has been defined" is not so straightforward. When the code runs, the *name* of the objects that it refers to have to exist. So, you can't do

```
f()
def f():...
```

because `f()` actually executes something. But definitions create a function object, without running it at the time. In the example, the function is claled at the last line of the script, and, by that time, both `f, g` do exist.

Comment: You might wanna add that neither function is actually called when they are defined. ANd when you do call any of them, both *are* defined.